# What does the minimum value of a function in 1 variable of an equation in 3 variable mean here ??

Tags: calculus, functions

> Consider $\phi(a,b,t) = a^4 -5 a^2 +b ^2 +5t^2 -4bt -2t +33/4$ , where $a,b,t \in R $. Given $f(t)$ and $g(b)$ are minimum values of $\phi(a,b,t)$ , Evaluate:
>
> $$\int {\frac{dx}{f(x)}} \text{and} \int e^x g(x) dx $$

Now the main problem I had was since $\phi(a,b,t)$ is a combined function of $a,b,t$ , I couldn't understand what $f(t)$ and $g(b)$ are. As for say $f(t)$, I could obviously change the parameters a,b and get a new function , but in the question after evaluating , we have to give our answer, without any $a,b$ or $t$ in it. Please help

Comment: $f(t)$ is the function in $t$ for the minimum value of $\phi(a, b, t)$, i.e for a given $t$, what is the minimum value (over all $a, b$) of $\phi(a, b, t)$?

Answer (score 1):

The the value of the function $f$ at the point $t_0$ is the minimum value of $\phi(a,b,t_0)$. That is,
$$f(t_0):=\min_{a,b}\phi(a,b,t_0).$$
Phrased differently; for a given point $t_0$ the value of $f(t_0)$ is the minimum of $\phi(a,b,t_0)$ over all possible values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more. I mean what exactly are the functions ?? As for any $\t_0$ , f and g will have $\t_0$  in them

Comment: @DivMit I have added another way to say the same thing. What part is unclear?